# PHP: Txt para Array relacionando as linhas.

Tags: php, array, txt

seguinte, eu tenho um arquivo de texto (.txt) com a seguinte estrutura:

```
|100|Nome do Cliente|
|200|Produto 1|R$100|
|200|Produto 2|R$200|
|200|Produto 3|R$300|
```

Resumindo, sempre que a linha começa com |100|, todos os |200| que seguem abaixo estão relacionados ao |100| acima. 
Usando EXPLODE no PHP, tenho o seguinte Array:

```
Array(
     [0] => 
     [1] => 100
     [2] => Nome do Cliente
)
...
```

Ou seja, um array pra cada linha. 
Gostaria de relacionar, no próprio array, os produtos ao cliente, numa estrutura em que os produtos fiquem no mesmo array que o Cliente, algo como:

```
Array(
     [0] => 
     [1] => 100
     [2] => Nome do Cliente
     Array(
          [0] =>  
          [1] => Produto 1
          [2]=>R$100
     )
     Array(
          [0] => 
          [1] => Produto 2
          [2] => R$200
     )
     ... etc
)
```

Alguém pode me dar uma luz de como relacionar isso?

Comment: Todos clientes começam com 100 e todos produtos com 200?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu faria desta maneira, com o `fopen` e `feof` pra ajudar a poupar memória e com `trim` pra limpar quebras de linha:

```
<?php
function tratarDados($linha) {
    //Remove espaços do começo e fim nos nomes, valores e etc
    return array_map('trim', explode('|', $linha));
}

$handle = fopen('arquivo.txt', "r");

$vetor = array();
$i = -1;

while (feof($handle) === false) {
    $line = fgets($handle);
    $line = trim($line); //Remove espaços e \r
    $line = trim($line, '|'); //Remove | do começo e do fim

    //Quando encontra o 100 adiciona um novo elemento
    if (strpos ($line, '100|') === 0) {
         $vetor[] = tratarDados($line);
         ++$i;
    } elseif ($i > -1) {
         //Se já existe um cliente no vetor adiciona os produtos pra ele
         $vetor[$i][] = tratarDados($line);
    }
}

fclose($handle);

print_r($vetor);
```

O arquivo.txt ficou assim:

```
|100|João|
|200|Produto 1|R$100|
|200|Produto 2|R$200|
|200|Produto 3|R$300|
|100|Jose|
|200|Produto 1|R$100|
|200|Produto 2|R$200|
|200|Produto 3|R$300|
|100|Marcos|
|200|Produto 1|R$100|
|200|Produto 2|R$200|
|200|Produto 3|R$300|
|100|Paulo|
|200|Produto 1|R$100|
|200|Produto 2|R$200|
|200|Produto 3|R$300|
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => João
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 200
                    [1] => Produto 1
                    [2] => R$100
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 200
                    [1] => Produto 2
                    [2] => R$200
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 200
                    [1] => Produto 3
                    [2] => R$300
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => Jose
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 200
                    [1] => Produto 1
                    [2] => R$100
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 200
                    [1] => Produto 2
                    [2] => R$200
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 200
                    [1] => Produto 3
                    [2] => R$300
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => Marcos
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 200
                    [1] => Produto 1
                    [2] => R$100
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 200
                    [1] => Produto 2
                    [2] => R$200
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 200
                    [1] => Produto 3
                    [2] => R$300
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => Paulo
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 200
                    [1] => Produto 1
                    [2] => R$100
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 200
                    [1] => Produto 2
                    [2] => R$200
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 200
                    [1] => Produto 3
                    [2] => R$300
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Assim como o acima, ambos funcionaram de forma magnífica. Porém o seu, pra mim, teve um uso melhor devido ao loop de arquivos incontáveis que tenho numa pasta, pra tratar tudo um a um, o seu é mais usual. 
Obrigado a todos

Comment: @Marcio o script estava gerando uma dimensão a mais, eu corrigi ele

Comment: @GuilhermeNasdcimento, eu meio que fiz uma certa confusão ontem quando vi outros arquivos que preciso transferir para banco de dados, onde há vários níveis de relacionamento. Eu tentei editar a pergunta aqui mas aparecia mensagem de que eu não podia editar. Acima do Cliente e produtos, há também a empresa responsável pela venda. Se puder, por favor, veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117590/php-txt-para-array-com-v%C3%A1rios-n%C3%ADveis) . Super obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Então não da para fazer exatamente desse seu jeito porque um grupo de matriz deve estar dentro de outro, sendo assim o mais fácil é associar uma nova posição e agrupar essa sub-matriz dentro. Não sei se ficou claro aqui vai o código de exemplo.

```
<?php
// Massa de dados de exemplo
$txt = "|100|Nome do Cliente|
|200|Produto 1|R$100|
|200|Produto 2|R$200|
|200|Produto 3|R$300|
|100|Nome do Cliente 2|
|200|Produto 1|R$100|
|200|Produto 2|R$200|
|200|Produto 3|R$300|";

$array_final = array(); // Inicia uma Matriz vazia
$temp_cliente = 0; // Variável de controle de posição dos clientes

// Quebra as linhas da sua fonte (no caso minha variável simples)
// No seu vem a leitura do TXT aqui nessa parte
$divide_linhas = explode("\n", $txt);

// Percorre todas as linhas
for ($l = 0; $l < count($divide_linhas); $l++) {
 list($a0, $a1, $a2, $a3) = explode("|", $divide_linhas[$l]);

 if ($a1 == "100") {
  if ($l > 0) { $temp_cliente++; } // Ajuste para primeira linha apenas  

  // Monta a primeira estrutura da Matriz do cliente
  $array_final[$temp_cliente] = array($a1, $a2, array());
 } else {
  // Monta a sub-matriz dentro da primeira   
  $array_final[$temp_cliente][2][] = array($a1, $a2, $a3);
 }
}

// Imprime o resultado
print_r($array_final);
?>
```

O resultado final sairá algo como isso *(abaixo)*, ai bastará você chamar o cliente e depois percorre a posição 2 e nessa estará todos os produtos daquele cliente em especial.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => Nome do Cliente
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 200
                            [1] => Produto 1
                            [2] => R$100
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 200
                            [1] => Produto 2
                            [2] => R$200
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 200
                            [1] => Produto 3
                            [2] => R$300
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Nossa valeu, ambos funcionaram de forma magnífica.