# PHP: TXT para Array com vários níveis

Tags: php, array, relacionamento, txt

Galera, ontem eu havia pedido help sobre o assunto [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117283/php-txt-para-array-relacionando-as-linhas) que, prontamente os amigos me ajudaram, porém dei de cara com outro problema:

Só depois percebi que o arquivo .TXT tem vários níveis, e não apenas 2 como eu havia observado ontem. Tentei de todas as formas alguma estratégia para resolver a questão mas tá complicado pra mim. Seguinte:

```
|0000|nome da empresa|cnpj|
|0100|nome do cliente|cod|
|0150|produto 1|preço|
|0150|produto 2|preço|
|0150|produto 3|preço|
|0100|nome do cliente|cod|
|0150|produto 1|preço|
|0150|produto 2|preço|
|0150|produto 3|preço|
```

1. |0000| é o registro da empresa e engloba tudo, é único em cada TXT e é sempre ÚNICO na primeira linha.
2. |0100| é o registro do cliente, que fica dentro do array da empresa (em 0000).
3. |0150| são os produtos comprados por esse cliente, dentro do array do cliente.

No caso, o resultado esperado é o array abaixo:

```
Array(
[0] => 0000, 
[1] => nome da empresa, 
[2] => cnpj, 
     [3] => array(
          [0] => 0100,
          [2] => nome do cliente, 
          [3] => cod, 
          [4] => array(
                     [0] => 0150, 
                     [1] => produto 1, 
                     [2] => preço,
                 )
          [5] => array(
                     [0] => 0150,
                     [1] => produto 2,
                     [2] => preço,
                 )
                 ...
      )
      ...
)
```

Lamento estar repetindo a pergunta, eu não consegui de jeito nenhum editar minha pergunta anterior, além de achar que a outra também tem uma resposta muito útil para o formato apresentado lá. 
Espero que exista possibilidade de manter essa estrutura num loop onde há vários clientes e produtos dentro de uma mesma empresa. 
Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Perdeu acesso a outra conta?

Comment: É `0100` ou `100`? É 0150 ou 150? Teu exemplo está dificil de entender.

Comment: Outra duvida o, só tem um `0000` pra cada .txt?

Comment: Eu não tava conseguindo ativar a conta, toda vez que eu fazia login dava a mesma coisa (conclua seu registro) e eu tentando adivinhar como fazer isso. Limpei o cache do navegador e aí deu certo. 
Bom, é 0100, eu digitei "100" por erro, já tava bem cansado. 
Cada txt tem um único 0000 e é SEMPRE a primeira linha. No TXT do exemplo de ontem que me mandaram não estava completo, o que deu em confusão.

Comment: Eu editei a questão para que fique mais fácil de compreender tanto para quem responder, quanto para outros possíveis usuários com a mesma dúvida. ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: eu estive muito ocupado, amanhã te dou uma atenção

Comment: Tudo bem, fique à vontade :)

Comment: Quantas vezes o  0100 vai aparecer nesse arquivo ?
É sempre ?

Comment: Ele aparece sempre